# Clearing a Date Field value in the Edit Node form

Tags: 7, datetime

I have a content type with a date field (field_acquisition_date) and I'm using the Popup Calendar widget in the form UI. If a user...

- puts a value into that field and save the node
- then edits the node again
- clears out the value
- and saves the node a second time

the original value is still in that date field. How can the user set that field value to empty/NULL while using the edit form?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the default value to 'No default value' in the content type of where the field is created.

Please see in the screenshot

[image]